# How could I allow to put audio and music through file upload in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I would like to allow the audio,doc and video file type in uploading file. My question is, how should I allow the audio,doc and video through file upload? In my code the file that allows are :png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,docx. This is my code

**My controller**

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Validator;
use Redirect;
use Request;
use Session;
use App\Administrator;
class ApplyController extends Controller 
{
  public function multipleUpload()
  {
    return view('multiple_upload');
  }
  public function multipleUploadPost() {
    // getting all of the post data
    $files = Input::file('images');
    // Making counting of uploaded images
    $file_count = count($files);
    // start count how many uploaded
    $uploadcount = 0;
    foreach($files as $file) {
      $rules = array('file' => 'required'); //'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,docx' 
      $validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);

      if($validator->passes()){
        $destinationPath = 'uploads';
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension()  ;
        if($extension == "jpg" || $extension == "PNG" )
        {
          $destinationPath = 'uploads/image';

        }
        else if ($extension == "docx" || $extension == "doc")
        {
          $destinationPath = 'uploads/documents';

        }
        else if ($extension == "pdf")
        {
          $destinationPath = 'uploads/pdf';

        }
        else if ($extension == "xls")
        {
          $destinationPath = 'uploads/excel';

        }
        $changeFileName = str_random(40).'.'.$extension;

        $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $changeFileName);
        $uploadcount ++;
        Administrator::create([ // Administrator is the name of my model
            'original_filename' => $filename, // Insert the image to the database in column "image"
            'change_filename' => $changeFileName // Insert the image to the database in column "image"
        ]);
      }

    }
    if($uploadcount == $file_count){
      Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully'); 
      return Redirect::to('multiple-upload');
    } 
    else {
      Session::flash('alert', 'Upload failed'); 

      return Redirect::to('multiple-upload')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }
  }
}
```

**My view**

```
<div class="text-content">
  <div class="span7 offset1">
  @if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert-box success">
      <h2>{!! Session::get('success') !!}</h2>
    </div>
  @endif
  <div class="secure">Upload form</div>
  {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'apply/multiple_upload','method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true)) !!}

    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
      {!! Form::file('images[]', array('multiple'=>true)) !!}
  <p class="errors">{!!$errors->first('images')!!}</p>
  @if(Session::has('error'))
  <p class="errors">{!! Session::get('error') !!}</p>
  @endif
     </div>
</div>
{!! Form::submit('Submit', array('class'=>'send-btn')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Comment: The same code should work for vidoe, audio, any type of files. Have you tried uploading video or audio with this code?

Comment: I tried to upload video or audio with it.. It said TokenMisMatch

Comment: This seems to be your upload max size reached. change the value in php.ini , upload_max_filesize = 2G post_max_size = 2G , restart your apache and try again.

Answer (score 0):

use Mime validation which will allow only those format which you specify

for ex:

```
    foreach ($files as $file){
        $validator = Validator::make(
            array(
                'file'              =>      $file,
                'extension'         =>      strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension()),
            ),
            [
                'file'              =>      'required|max:100000',
                'extension'         =>      'required|in:mp3,mp4,doc',
            ],[
                'file.required' => 'File is Required',
                'extension.in' => ' File Should be of type mp3,mp4 or doc'
            ]
        );
        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json(['status' => 'fail', 'data' => null, 'msg' => $validator->errors()], 200);
        }
        else{
            dd("success");
        }
    }
```

List of mime types Available

> http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

Hope this might help you

Comment: I changed my codes, and now it cant upload any file type

Comment: and yes after you change your php.ini file with increased value you will be able to upload and file with any extension using your previous code

Comment: As far as I understand to my code.. In this code " $rules = array('file' => 'required'); " it will validate the file that uploaded(specially in 'required'). So how could I find 'required' so that I can add other file type?

Comment: you dont have to give explict rule array $rules = array('file' => 'required').....

in validator 1st array is for variable and 2nd is for rules.

Comment: the part you added for validator is itself self sufficient to check if file is present with max file size and of specified mime type i.e. mp3,mp4 and doc

Comment: You mean that codes that you're suggested? Can you explain further? I dont get it, sorry

Comment: Check the edit i have made and try with the same Validator what i have edited for your code ...Let me know in case i am wrong

Comment: Comment your code after foreach loop till the end of validator and try using my code

Comment: Sir, how do i change the code? I mean, im not using ajax.. Just pure laravel file upload

Comment: In ApplyController where you have written your foreach loop please comment that and paste my code and see if its running

Comment: Oohh i see.. wait a minute

Comment: Result {"status":"fail","data":null,"msg":{"file":["The file failed to upload."]}}

Comment: may be because in php.ini your max_upload_size and post upload size is less

Comment: changes this values in php.ini upload_max_filesize = 2G post_max_size = 2G and restart your apache service

Comment: WOW MAN, THANKS A LOT! I'VE FOUND MY ERROR.. Now it's okay.. I can upload any type of files! Thanks for your effort!